# linux perf report inconsistent behavior

Tags: linux, perf

I have an application I'm profiling using `perf` and I find the results when using `perf report` are not consistent, and I can't discern the pattern.

I start the application and profile it by pid for 60 seconds:

`perf record -p <pid> -o <file> sleep 60`

And when I pull the results in with `perf report -i <file>`, sometimes I see a "+" in the far left column that allows me to drill down into the function call trees when I press ENTER, and sometimes that "+" is not there. It seems to be dependent on some property of the recorded file, in that I have a collection of recorded files, some which allow this drill down and some which do not.

Any suggestions on how to get consistent behavior here would be appreciated.

Comment: Not consistent how?

Comment: The "+" in the leftmost column for drilling down into the call tree is not always there. I would like it to be.

Comment: Try running for longer than 60 seconds, e.g. five minutes.

Comment: I've tried different sample lengths from 10s to 400s and the results are inconsistent. Sometimes it's there, sometimes not.

Comment: A working hypothesis is: (1) This is a *sampling* profiler which will 'hit' different functions statistically, leading to different call trees if some functions are not 'hit' on a particular run (2) Sampling isn't starting at exactly the same point in each run. If there is a setting for changing the sampling frequency, try that (ideally chose a sampling frequency relatively prime to the time-slice frequency, to minimize the "stampeding herd" effect).

Answer (score 0):

The default event being measured by perf record is cpu-cycles.
(Or depending on the machine, sometimes cpu-cycles:p or cpu-cycles:pp)

Are you sure your application is not sleeping a lot? Does it consume a lot of cpu cycles?

Try a perf measurement on something that stresses the CPU by doing a lot of computations:

```
$ apt-get install stress
$ perf record -e cpu-cycles --call-graph fp stress --cpu 1 --timeout 5
$ perf report
```

Subsequent runs should then show more or less similar results.

In case your program is CPU intensive, and call stacks do differ a lot between runs, then you may want to look at the --call-graph option, as perf can record call-graphs with different methods:

- fp (function pointer)
- lbr (last branch record)
- dwarf

Maybe different methods give better results.